# Unpopulate Google Form by default

Tags: google-forms

I made a survey in Google Forms. It consists of several multiple-choice questions. When I preview the form or use the link I would send to participants, some of the answers are already populated/preselected.

Because I - logically - do not want to suggest a particular answer, nor give participants the idea they already answered a question, I am wondering: **is there any way to have all questions be unpopulated by default (or somehow deselect these preselected answers)?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regular link to invite users to fill a form doesn't automatically populate responses, for that there is a special URL but it's very likely that the form autofill feature from your web browser is filling the responses.

To verify this try another web browser that you haven't used to open your form.

NOTE:

Your web browser should have a feature to clear form autofill values.

Relate from Super User:

- [How to delete SPECIFIC autofill entries from Google Chrome?](https://superuser.com/q/1289097/152004)

Comment: Thank you so much. I opened the link in Private Mode in Firefox, and, indeed, no answers were preselected.